# regex: don't match number preceded by certain character

Tags: python, regex

Following code extracts the first sequence of numbers that appear in a string:

```
num = re.findall(r'^\D*(\d+)', string)
```

I'd like to add that the regular expression doesn't match numbers preceded by `v`or `V`.

Example:

```
string = 'foobarv2_34 423_wd"
Output: '34'
```

Comment: You may use `(?<![vV])\d+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the first match, you need to use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search), not `re.findall`.

In this case, you can use a simpler regular expression like `(?<!v)\d+` with `re.I`:

```py
import re
m = re.search(r'(?<!v)\d+', 'foobarv2_34 423_wd', re.I)
if m:
    print(m.group()) # => 34
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/gQqSt9).

*Details*

- `(?<!v)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `v` (or `V` since `re.I` is used) immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d+` - one or more digits.

If you cannot use `re.search` for some reason, you can use

```
^.*?(?<!v)(\d+)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GbVvVf/1). Note that `\D*` (zero or more non-digits) is replaced with `.*?` that matches zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible (with `re.S` or `re.DOTALL`, it will also match line breaks) since there is a need to match all digits not preceded with `v`.

More details:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?<!v)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `v` (or `V` since `re.I` is used) immediately to the left of the current location
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digtis.